# angularjs - one module define in multi place

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem when define angularjs module in multi place

```
angular.module('ty', [])
.directive('v1', function() {
      return{
        restrict: "E",      
        template: '<div>1</div>'
      };
});

angular.module('ty', [])
.directive('v2', function() {
      return{
        restrict: "E",      
        template: '<div>2</div>'
      };
})
```

This problem can solve by define a variable like this

```
var a = angular.module('ty', []);
a.directive('v1', function() { ...
a.directive('v2', function() { ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/66Je2/1/

My question is: Can we define module in multi place without global variable ?

Comment: See if this helps -- "Using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module `myModule` and overwrite any existing module named `myModule`. Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module." -- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

In your case, your are re-creating your module again and removing the previous one.